# Lua Function Multiple Return Values, Print(returnvalue) Results in Attempt to Concatenate String and Nil

Tags: function, lua, return, null

The following function `getTank()` works (if not used as a function to print `fluidName` for example). The issue comes when I return the values and then try to access them outside of the function. The result is `'attempt to concatenate string and nil'` at the lines: `mon2.write(returnedVariable)` for example which is outside of the function.

If I simply do the following:

```
for k,v in pairs(tableInfo) do amount=v.amount end 
print(amount)
```

outside of the function, it gives the correct value.

```
function getTank(tankPeriph)
    -- This has been tested and works

    local tableInfo = tankPeriph.getTankInfo("unknown")
    local fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity

    for k,v in pairs(tableInfo) do
        fluidRaw = v.rawName
        fluidName = v.name
        fluidAmount = v.amount
        fluidCapacity = v.capacity
    end
    return fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity
end

function dispTanks()
    -- working on it

    -- TANK 0
    mon2.setCursorPos(rowPos, ironTank0Col)
    mon2.clearLine()
    local fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity = getTank(irontank0)
    mon2.write("Iron Tank 0 (" .. fluidName .. ") : " .. fluidAmount)

    -- TANK 1
    mon2.setCursorPos(rowPos, ironTank1Col)
    mon2.clearLine()
    local fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity = getTank(irontank1)
    mon2.write("Iron Tank 1 (" .. fluidName .. ") : " .. fluidAmount)

    -- TANK 2
    mon2.setCursorPos(rowPos, ironTank2Col)
    mon2.clearLine()
    local fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity = getTank(irontank2)
    mon2.write("Iron Tank 2 (" .. fluidName .. ") : " .. fluidAmount)

    -- TANK 3
    mon2.setCursorPos(rowPos, ironTank3Col)
    mon2.clearLine()
    local fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity = getTank(irontank3)
    mon2.write("Iron Tank 3 (" .. fluidName .. ") : " .. fluidAmount)

    -- TANK 4
    mon2.setCursorPos(rowPos, ironTank4Col)
    mon2.clearLine()
    local fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity = getTank(irontank4)
    mon2.write("Iron Tank 4 (" .. fluidName .. ") : " .. fluidAmount)

end
```

Comment: Twice you use the idiom `for k,v in pairs(t) do ... end` where you capture the value from the last iteration of the loop to use later. Since `pairs()` does not guarantee any particular order of traversal of the table (and can, in fact, go in different orders for the same table content), this is probably not doing what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getTank(tankPeriph)
    -- This has been tested and works

    local tableInfo = tankPeriph.getTankInfo("unknown") -- Local to the getTank function.

    for k,v in pairs(tableInfo) do
        local fluidRaw = v.rawName -- local to this for loop
        local fluidName = v.name -- local to this for loop
        local fluidAmount = v.amount -- local to this for loop
        local fluidCapacity = v.capacity -- local to this for loop
    end

    return fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity -- Returning the values of global variables (which are nil).
end
```

As indicated in my edited snippet above your locals are not local to where you think they are and you aren't returning their values from your function correctly. Move the local declaration for those variables to outside the for loop (keep the assignment in the for loop if you need it, though I can't really imagine that you do since you only get the last values in the loop that way) and your function should "work".

Comment: Assuming the last entry that pairs(tableInfo) returns has the values you expect it to. Note that pairs doesn't have a defined order for how it will return the table key/value pairs.

Comment: Here is the table itself:

 {[1]={["rawName"]="fluid.honey",["amount"]=12150,["capacity"]=576000,["name"]="honey",["id"]=52,},}

Comment: If that table is tableInfo then it should work (and a quick mock-up test works here). Wrap the variables in your monX.write calls in calls to tostring() (e.g. `.. tostring(fluidName) ..`) and see where you get nils and where you get values.

Comment: That got it. Thank you very much. The issue was tank0 was empty, so it was returning nil for amount.

Comment: The only issue now is fluidName is actually showing the amount inside the tank instead.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Also the value for "name" in that table you pasted contains some non-printable characters, is that intentional? How does monX.write deal with them?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about non-printable characters (the value is "honey"). The table comes from a game mod (I can't change it). I got some help to update the code. http://pastebin.com/pEwFuPUQ Now the last remaining issue is that I'm getting numbers like "5" for what should be 12,500 (for amount).

Comment: Copy and paste the text from your comment here into a text editor (something fancier than notepad) and you should see the extra characters). I do at least.

Comment: You are assigning both amount and id to fluidAmount in each of your returns from getTank in that paste. Fix that and your problem should go away. You should probably add the new code to the post too.

Answer (score 1):

The "local" qualifier limits the scope to block or chunk, so the locals in the loop in getTank() are scoped to the loop; outside the loop their values are lost. So when getTank returns, the variables it returns have not been defined in the scope of the function, so they are all nil. See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.6 for useful examples.

But since that doesn't seem to fix your problem, I wager you have an additional issue, namely that `local tableInfo` is empty table, which implies `tankPeriph.getTankInfo("unknown")` returns empty table (not `nil`, but `{}`).